# Speak and show message boxes at the same time in C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm trying to build an application that displays message boxes showing the phoneme at the exact moment that it is being spoken. The problem is these message boxes wait to display the phonemes after the speech is over. How can I do the 2 things at the same time?

```
void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{  
    speech = new SpeechSynthesizer();      
    speech.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    speech.SpeakAsync(e.Result.Text);
    speech.PhonemeReached += speech_PhonemeReached;
}
void speech_PhonemeReached(object sender, PhonemeReachedEventArgs e)
{
    if (new[] {"a͡i","o"}.Contains(e.Phoneme))
       MessageBox.Show(e.Phoneme);
}
```

I'm still learning c# and I'm not really sure how to use threading, but this is the part of my code related to the speech recognizer:

```
Thread q = new Thread( ()=> sre.SpeechRecognized += (s, args) =>
    {
         foreach (RecognizedPhrase phrase in args.Result.Alternates)
         {
            if (phrase.Confidence > 0.9f)
                sre_SpeechRecognized(s, args);
         }
    });
q.Start();
```

Hoping anyone can help me...

Answer (score 1):

Run the speech recognizer in it's own thread and show the msg box on main thread using Invoke.

```
void speech_PhonemeReached(object sender, PhonemeReachedEventArgs e)
{
    if (new[] {"a͡i","o"}.Contains(e.Phoneme))
       this.Invoke(new Action(() => { MessageBox.Show(this, e.Phoneme); }));
}
```

Comment: you mean speech synthesizer? anyway..i tried both of them and its still not working...

Comment: The key here is threading. @user1840006 Are you running the display and recognizer on different threads?

Comment: well, i used the idea of Johnny Mopp and now I think I am, but still not working.

Comment: The problem was really about threading. I used the msg box in another thread and the method SpeakAsync(). Thank you for the help!!!